# Using cqlsh with -f option

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

Can we use cqlsh -f like it?

```
psql -U maint_sa -p 3254 postgres -f - << EOT
SHOW ALL;
EOT
```

On cqlsh I have following:

```
cqlsh -f - << EOT
> DISCRIBE KEYSTORE ks1;
> EOT
Can't open '-': [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '-'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried echoing it to the command line:

`echo "DESC KEYSPACE ks1; exit" | cqlsh`